# spec file requires rpm-build... change requires dependent on os-release?

Tags: rpmbuild, build-dependencies

I'm building a spec file that requires `/usr/bin/rpmbuild` to be installed. Under Opensuse13.1 that is very simple: I just add this line in my spec file:

```
Requires: rpm-build
```

and this works nicely on Opensuse13.1

Yet When I try to build and install this package on opensuse12.1; this does not work, since the binary `/usr/bin/rpmbuild` is provided there by the package `rpm` and not by the package `rpm-build`.

How do I work around this problem? I didn't find a virtual package they both provide. Note that the package `rpm` also exists on opensuse13.1 and that `rpm-build` depends on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Requires: /usr/bin/rpmbuild
```